# have textview change style/attribute on touch roll-off

Tags: android, button, textview, touch

Ok, I simply can't figure this out for the life of me. I created a custom textview and I basically want it to be a button. I have all my code working except that I can't get it to detect when touched, and then the touch event rolls out of its boundary. Say the textview lights up grey when touched, then if the user drags their finger away to the left or right, I want to have the grey disappear and reset to its normal background color.

I realize I can just use the standard android button, but I don't like how it delays on changing color for the touch event. Maybe someone knows where the stock Button.java class code is, for the android API so I can look at that for hints?

I have tried getting the dimensions of the button with an on global listener and then tracking user touch events to be within those dimensions. And the dimensions and touch location are reported correctly and works sometimes, but it simply doesn't work reliably, maybe due to the user moving too quickly, for example. Even if I set the touch boundary a few pixels inside of the actual boundary.

Comment: what does "I can't get it to detect when touched, and then the touch event rolls out of its boundary" mean?

Comment: `Button` source code: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/Button.java

Comment: @blakcbelt, sorry, that language wasn't clear. I meant that I cannot correctly get the "roll-off" event to be detected. If the user has touched the textview and then dragged the finger out of the bounds of the textview, I would like to be able to change the textview's attributes once the finger leaves its bounds.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thanks for the link... not sure why I didn't just think to do search in my local AOSP repository! However, Button.java doesn't seem to have what I thought it would. I figured I would see some stuff in there about the xml attributes such as the selector properties, etc.

What I would like to do is extend TextView and essentially create my own custom button class where I can specify the onPress, onTouch, onFocus state in via xml or dynamically. Basically almost identical to Button, but with some tweaks.

Comment: Most of that logic is in `TextView`, IIRC. `Button` mostly just has a different `StateListDrawable` background.